# MySQL access denied for user 'root' and 'pma'. (Windows)

Tags: mysql

This problem occured when I changed password in phpMyAdmin. I've already tried to check/change ***config.inc.php***, tried to reset password via cmd with ***mysqld --default-file --init-file*** or when I'm trying to log with **mysql -u root** and I keep getting the same message:

```
Access denied for the user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES/NO) - both happen
```

Comment: if you do a bit of googling you will find how to reset the root password for mysql

Comment: Have you already tried to connect to `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost? MySQL treats socket files (or named pipes on windows) different for user rights, so this could be a problem.

Comment: @LelioFaieta If you know any other method beside the ones I mentioned please feel free to post them :)

Comment: Put a bit of effort doing some research on your own. Just search for MySQL reset root password. Plenty of answers from this site too.